# Using the free space on an ESXi datastore with an existing Centos VM of limited size

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have ESXi 4 on a home-built server with a 925GB RAID5 array (adaptec 2405 card) with a single Centos5.4 VM running on it. The VM has a provisioned size of 20GB which I can't seem to increase using the vSphere client. Now I would like to either increase the size of the Centos VM to use more of the free space or I would like to somehow use the datastore as another volume that can be easily accessed from the Centos VM. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried from the vSphere client?

Is the virtual machine powered off?
Are there any snapshots on the virtual machine?

The machine needs to be powered off and without snapshots before resizing the drive. After you resize the virtual disk you can use gParted and/or LVM tools to resize the partition.

Comment: All good ideas Andy, I think both you and I have had training and/or read the manual. Fingers-crossed Ben gives this a go soon ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slight delay. Been looking through the vsphere client manual but still can't find any instructions on how to resize a VM (..bearing in mind it is already THICKLY provisioned). I did find out that I can add a new virtual HDD looks like the only solution....unless I missed something.

Comment: Make sure the VM meets the requirements in the above posted answer. Right click and go to 'Edit Settings'. Select the virtual disk that you want to resize. On the right side, you should be able to type in a new size in GB. This will resize the virtual drive... but not the partition that the operating system uses.

Comment: As it turned out the block size of 4MB limited the maximum size of a virtual disk to 256GB which wasn't big enough and rather than re-building the datastore with a larger block size I decided to create a set of three new virtual disks which I then used to make a new LVM volume group etc. I blogged this in my blog here: http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=366

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a new vmdk file with the desired size and add it to your CentOS VM as another drive.

Comment: yes, this is probably the easiest route I reckon, thanks.